# Редактирование csv

Tags: c#, unity3d, csv

Не могу никак найти как редактировать csv файлы в юнити, т.е. это я считываю из csv в массив строк `TextAsset TA = Resources.Load<TextAsset> ("123");`, а как потом сохранить изменения в файл? искал но так и не нашел.

**Суть вопроса:** как сохранить строку (массив строк) в csv файл в папке ресурсов?

Comment: Посмотрите тут [Dictionary CSV Extensions](https://github.com/ClnViewer/Dictionary-CSV-Extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.csv является обычным строковым файлом, в котором есть свои разделители. Например, по умолчанию - два значения разделённых ; поместятся в два столбца.

Другими словами правила записи такие же, как и у обычного текстового файла - через [File.WriteAllText()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2). О том, как его использовать - указано в документации.

Получить путь до папки проекта можно через [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html), соответственно до папки ресурсов  `Application.dataPath + "/Resources/"`. Соответственно, чтобы сохранить ваш файл, вам нужно сделать что-нибудь вроде

```
        TextAsset TA = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("123");
        string path = $"{Application.dataPath}/Resources/{TA.name}.csv";
        File.WriteAllText(path, TA.text);
```